# Presenting a Modal View inside a UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So in the root of my app, I have a `UITabVarController` (created in the storybaord).  And when the user goes to one of my tabs, I have a special class that initalizes by presenting a modal view controller.  So my question is: Is there a way to present this modal view inside the UITabBarController - So I will still see the other tabs, rather than being on top of them.

I was thinking something like:

```
self.parentViewController.tabBarController presentViewController
self.parentViewController ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your modal view controller one of the tabs or does it appear as a result of an action on one of the tabs (not an actual tab)?

Comment: The modal view is called from one of the tabs when it is loaded for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is a NavigationController instead of doing things modally.  You can hide the navigation bar if you don't need that.

Comment: This wont work because when the tab loads, a dummy view controller inits the special class, and then presents it modally.  If I just pushed the new VC, then if the user pressed the tab bar icon again, it would take them to the blank dummy VC - which is not what I want

Comment: Subclass the the UINavigationController, and set it up so that viewWillAppear pushes the special class.  (Or just subclass the initial 'dummy' view to do that)

Comment: @Andrew, what do you want to happen when the modal view is dismissed? Also, what do you want to have happen when the user presses that tab bar a second time?